# ASP NET MVC Include double my view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I've got a little problem and don't know how to fix it.

When I write in my view and controller:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)

return View(db.Product.Include(p=>p.Category).OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).ToList());
```

This happens:
[image]

When I change it to:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)

return View(db.Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).ToList());
```

This happens:
[image]

So everything is ok, but it doesn't display category names. How can I fix it?

EDIT1:

```
public partial class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Promotion { get; set; }
        public string Image1 { get; set; }
        public string Image2 { get; set; }
        public string Image3 { get; set; }
        public string Image4 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int ClientID { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add GroupBy to your expression.Change

```
View(db.Product.Include(p=>p.Category).OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).ToList());
```

to

```
View(db.Product.Include(p=>p.Category).OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).GroupBy(P => P.ProductID).ToList())
```

Comment: Getting this error on OrderByDescending:
'IGrouping<int, Product>' does not contain a definition for 'ProductID' and no extension method 'ProductID' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<int, Product>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product]'.

Comment: when you try wirte "GroupBy(P => P." do you have "ProductID" by intellisense?

Comment: what is you model for view?

Comment: @model IEnumerable<AMBIT_CMS_MVC.Areas.Admin.Models.Product>

Comment: My guess is you have to change one of your helpers in view. but don't know which one. you should check it to see by deleting which helper you view works. Then change it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96929/discussion-between-hadee-and-ashiv3r).

Comment: try this
View(db.Product.OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID).Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid).GroupBy(P => P.ProductID).Include(p=>p.Category).ToList());

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that for some reason you get multiple identical items. You can get the distinct items this way:

```
var results = db.Product
    .Include(p=>p.Category)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.ProductID)
    .Where(c => c.ClientID == clientid)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList());
return View(results);
```

But even better would be to investigate why you get multiple identical items. In that case, remove the `Distinct()` clause and put a breakpoint on the last statement. Next, check the results. There must be a property that makes the first item with Id = 4 different from the second item with Id 4.

Comment: Don't know it. It's saving in DB normally - just one item. And your answer is just mixing it.

Comment: Mixing? What do you mean? Can you add the `Product` class to the question?

Comment: There are also doubled items, but only order by ID is mixing.